# Debugging .NET Core under Linux

Tags: linux, debugging, .net-core, lldb

Currently I am trying to debug a Linux .NET Core application under Linux.

The trouble is, it fails somewhere right in the beginning, and I cannot get where. Logging is impossible under current circumstances.

As far as I can see on the Internet, and (severely avoiding any kind of systematizedness and consequtiveness) on MSDN specifically, the only [currently available options](https://blog.lextudio.com/the-rough-history-of-net-core-debuggers-b9fb206dc4aa) for Linux are:

1. [debug remotely](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-dotnet-core-linux-with-ssh?view=vs-2019) (would not do well in my case);
2. [Rider EAP](https://www.jetbrains.com/rider/nextversion/) by Jetbrains (proprietary decision);
3. [using lldb](https://codeblog.dotsandbrackets.com/command-line-debugging-core-linux/).

So, my questions are:

1. Is there any way to launch the .NET Core self-contained app (via the "dotnet Some.dll" command) in such a way that it instantly breaks (i.e. as if there was a breakpoint) at the entry point?
2. If not, how can one launch lldb for a .NET Core console application attached (since numerous [examples](https://github.com/dotnet/diagnostics/issues/575) and [issues](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/10468) over the Internet all show attaching to the already-running .NET Core process)?
3. Once again, there is the dotnet-dump utility, which works with already-running processes as well - so that, even dumps are an unavailable ooption for processes that crash almost instantly. I expected there might have been ways to make it dump like (imaginary) "dotnet-dump collect SomeInvocation.dll" along with ([actully existing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/dotnet-dump#using-dotnet-dump)) "dotnet-dump collect --process-id 1234". Is there such a way?

Comment: How did you end up solving this?

Comment: Could not find any solution yet ;d
Still, there are tools (NOT debuggers), that might help, like AvaloniaILSpy (fork of ILSpy, built with cross-platform AvaloniaUI)

Comment: To use lldb to run the .NET code, start lldb, then inside type the following 3 commands (I've separated them by | since this is a comment):
target create dotnet   |   settings set target.run-args <path-to-assembly>   |   r